# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower' - while trying to convert to lower case

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to extract text from a webpage and then convert all of it to lowercase, but I a, getting `object has no attribute` error. Any fix?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import operator

def webpage(url):
    word_list = []
    soup = bs(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')
    for text in soup('p', {'class': 'PE7lZb'}):
        content = text.string
        words = content.lower().split()

webpage("https://godan.business.site/")
```

Comment: You see that because, in some cases, `content is None`. There's not enough information here to tell you why.

Answer (score 1):

Here content is of different type than a str.You should check the existence of the content before calling .lower()

```
content = text.string
words = content.lower().split() if content and isinstance(content,str) else None
```